# Formulario con select dependientes multinivel

Tags: php, mysql, formularios, combobox

necesito crear un formulario para dar de alta clientes desde PHP y grabar en MySQL. Los campos para nombre, apellidos, teléfono serían de entrada libre, pero me gustaría que, para registrar las direcciones:

1. Elegir provincia de una select que lea las provincias de una tabla
2. Elegir municipio de una tabla dependiendo de la provincia seleccionada en el anterior
3. Elegir calle de una tabla dependiendo del municipio seleccionado en el paso 2

He estado mirando ejemplos, pero no logro entender por donde empezar y la mayoría solo hacen dos combos dependientes.
Agradecería cualquier pista o código e ejemplo para empezar.
Gracias,

Comment: Lo puedes hacer utilizando **Ajax** y escuchando el evento **Onchange** de los select, debes agregar un intento para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida y en base a eso resolver tus dudas.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno vamos a darte un ejemplo lo mas completoposible, pero te recuerdo que es tu tarea y tienes que adaptarla a tus necesidades:

---

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo crear un formulario en PHP para dar de alta clientes en una base de datos MySQL, incluyendo la funcionalidad de selección de provincias, municipios y calles:

1. Crear la tabla "provincias" en la base de datos MySQL y llenarla con los datos de las provincias:

```
CREATE TABLE provincias (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO provincias (nombre) VALUES
    ('Provincia 1'),
    ('Provincia 2'),
    ('Provincia 3');
```

2. Crear la tabla "municipios" en la base de datos MySQL y llenarla con los datos de los municipios asociados a las provincias:

```
CREATE TABLE calles (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    municipio_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (municipio_id) REFERENCES municipios(id)
);

INSERT INTO calles (nombre, municipio_id) VALUES
    ('Calle 1', 1),
    ('Calle 2', 1),
    ('Calle 3', 2),
    ('Calle 4', 2),
    ('Calle 5', 3),
    ('Calle 6', 3),
    ('Calle 7', 4),
    ('Calle 8', 4),
    ('Calle 9', 5),
    ('Calle 10', 5);
```

3. Crear el formulario en PHP para dar de alta clientes:

```
<?php
// Conexión a la base de datos
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'nombre_de_tu_base_de_datos';
$username = 'tu_usuario';
$password = 'tu_contraseña';

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Error de conexión a la base de datos: " . $e->getMessage());
}

// Obtener provincias
$provincias = $conn->query("SELECT id, nombre FROM provincias")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Obtener municipios de la primera provincia por defecto
$provinciaId = !empty($_POST['provincia']) ? $_POST['provincia'] : $provincias[0]['id'];
$municipios = $conn->query("SELECT id, nombre FROM municipios WHERE provincia_id = $provinciaId")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Obtener calles del primer municipio por defecto
$municipioId = !empty($_POST['municipio']) ? $_POST['municipio'] : $municipios[0]['id'];
$calles = $conn->query("SELECT id, nombre FROM calles WHERE municipio_id = $municipioId")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Procesar formulario
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    $calle = $_POST['calle'];

    // Guardar en la base de datos
    // Aquí debes agregar el código para insertar los datos en la tabla correspondiente
}
?>

<form method="POST" action="">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" required>

    <label for="apellidos">Apellidos:</label>
    <input type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" required>

    <label for="telefono">Teléfono:</label>
    <input type="tel" id="telefono" name="telefono" required>

    <label for="provincia">Provincia:</label>
    <select id="provincia" name="provincia">
        <?php foreach ($provincias as $provincia) { ?>
            <option value="<?= $provincia['id'] ?>" <?= ($provincia['id'] == $provinciaId) ? 'selected' : '' ?>>
                <?= $provincia['nombre'] ?>
            </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>

    <label for="municipio">Municipio:</label>
    <select id="municipio" name="municipio">
        <?php foreach ($municipios as $municipio) { ?>
            <option value="<?= $municipio['id'] ?>" <?= ($municipio['id'] == $municipioId) ? 'selected' : '' ?>>
                <?= $municipio['nombre'] ?>
            </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>

    <label for="calle">Calle:</label>
    <select id="calle" name="calle">
        <?php foreach ($calles as $calle) { ?>
            <option value="<?= $calle['id'] ?>"><?= $calle['nombre'] ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>

    <button type="submit">Guardar</button>
</form>
```

Hise unas pequeñas pruebas y para mi me resulto funcional, para tu pregunta, pero a lo mejor requieras algo distinto, si tu projecto cambia o crece.

Tambien puedes ver que implemento [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) para conectarse a la base de datos MySQL y obtener los datos de las provincias, municipios y calles. Los resultados se utilizan para poblar los select del formulario.

Cuando se envía el formulario, los datos se capturan en las variables correspondientes y se pueden guardar en la base de datos utilizando el código apropiado dentro del bloque `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')`.

Recuerda adaptar los detalles de conexión a tu configuración de base de datos y asegurarte de que los nombres de las tablas y columnas coincidan con los que has creado en tu base de datos.